# Can a "regular" eggplant be substituted for a chinese eggplant in a recipe?

Tags: substitutions, chinese-cuisine, eggplant

I'm going to attempt this [hot and sour chinese eggplant recipe](http://allrecipes.com/Recipe/Hot-and-Sour-Chinese-Eggplant/Detail.aspx) which calls for chinese eggplant. However, I only have a "regular" eggplant that you find in the typical American grocery store.

- Can this be used as a direct substitution?
- Are there any caveats I should be aware of?
- My eggplant is 9" long and 4" thick at it's widest. Is this equivalent to 2 long chinese eggplants?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Chinese eggplant will have a thinner skin, less seeds (read: less bitterness); as a result, it will have an overall more delicate flavor.

You can substitute a globe eggplant (the kind usually sold in American grocery stores) equally; just be aware you'll get extra "eggplant" flavor.

Since the recipe you're using has strong flavors already, this should not be a problem. However, if the recipe were using more delicate flavors, it would not turn out quite as the recipe author intended.

Comment: Agreed; it isn't a perfect substitute, but generally a pretty acceptable one. And yes, I'd use one good sized globe like that for 2 Asian eggplants. Close enough.

Comment: Remove seeds in center to minimize bitter taste.