# What do you call the eggplant cultivar commonly found in American grocery stores?

Tags: eggplant

In [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/6653/can-a-regular-eggplant-be-substituted-for-a-chinese-eggplant-in-a-recipe) of mine I didn't know what to call the specific type/species of eggplant that is commonly found in American grocery stores. What is this called?

It looks like:

[image: Eggplant]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"The most familiar Eggplants to us, the large dark purple ones, are called "Black Bell" or "Purple Globe." They're also called Globe Eggplant, Western Eggplant and American Eggplant. It's not known who exactly it was that thought this Eggplant was shaped anything like a globe."

http://www.practicallyedible.com/edible.nsf/pages/eggplant#ixzz0yQtZ0gpf

Answer (score 5):

This type of eggplant may be called Globe or American. 
The specific variety sold in grocery stores in the US is typically Black Beauty.

Answer (score 2):

From my part of the world (India) in english it is Brinjal. In my native tongue it globe shaped Brinjal is called 'Gutti Vankaya' a very popular dish in Andhra and there is a song on this vegetable :)

Comment: Errrr looking at typical pictures of 'Gutti Vankaya', that dish uses eggplants of a similar shape but MUCH smaller than what is actually typical on western supermarket shelves - most of the dishes on the first google images result page would need to be in a *two or three feet* in diameter wok or serving plate if they were made with typical western eggplants ... and they probably wouldnt even taste good.