# Is there a difference in the taste/seeds of egg-sized eggplants, and long and slim eggplants?

Tags: ingredient-selection, eggplant

Is there a difference in the taste/seeds of [egg sized eggplants or brinjals](http://www.google.co.in/imgres?q=brinjals%20long&um=1&hl=en&sa=N&biw=1024&bih=613&tbm=isch&tbnid=Z74owjawS_MzPM%3a&imgrefurl=http://www.sailusfood.com/2007/05/17/vankaya-kothimira-vepudu-brinjal-fresh-coriander-stir-fry/&docid=IudRCLW2R8iAkM&imgurl=http://cdn.sailusfood.com/wp-content/uploads/vankaya_purple_brinjals.JPG&w=313&h=400&ei=8kQuT_GrBonzrQfU3KDuDA&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=615&vpy=78&dur=598&hovh=254&hovw=199&tx=114&ty=139&sig=107061748674627861496&page=2&tbnh=137&tbnw=126&start=15&ndsp=20&ved=1t:429,r:13,s:15), and [long and slim eggplants or brinjals](http://www.google.co.in/imgres?q=brinjals%20long&um=1&hl=en&sa=N&biw=1024&bih=613&tbm=isch&tbnid=9uRBfx-FyypiNM%3a&imgrefurl=http://myworldofrecipes.blogspot.com/2009/12/stuffed-long-brinjals.html&docid=6V3y42ku7bqeKM&imgurl=http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_hkjOnjdDygU/SzONo-loseI/AAAAAAAAGAQ/k8QziQJNKm4/s400/HPIM9791.JPG&w=400&h=293&ei=8kQuT_GrBonzrQfU3KDuDA&zoom=1)?

They are different in shapes. Is there any other *"known/visible"* difference?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a "regular" eggplant be substituted for a chinese eggplant in a recipe?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/6653/can-a-regular-eggplant-be-substituted-for-a-chinese-eggplant-in-a-recipe)

Comment: Disagree on the duplicate vote. The questions may be related - closely related, even - but they're quite a ways off from being the *same* question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The varieties of the 2 eggplants shown in the pictures are not actually given, but to me the long variety looks like the Japanese/Chinese eggplant and the round variety looks like The Indian eggplant. By the way, there are many different eggplants out there. If you want to have a look, check out this: [website](http://www.foodsubs.com/Eggplants.html).

The Chinese eggplant has a thinner skin, more delicate flavour (I think sweeter) and less bitter seeds, although most modern varieties have bred these out anyway.

The Japanese eggplant is very similar and again has a thin delicate skin and sweet flavour.

The Indian eggplant is similar to the American eggplant with a thicker skin, more seeds and a stronger flavour.